# Re rendering angular 7 component

Tags: angular

I got this this hierarchy of component. A parent component who got 2 child components. I want the first child component to update a property of the parent component, after that the second child component re render.
I got main component with two child components: one with select html input and the second one a table of data, the data is coming from the main component as an input. The idea is when i change the selected value, i want to change the data in the main component so the data table can get the new data from the main component. 
How can i do that?

In the first child:

```
@Output() optionSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

@Input() data;

In the parent:

```
 @Input() displayOption: string;
 @Output() dataToSelect
```

When the displayOption updated , i want the second child re render

Comment: Please show your code. You need to look into `@Input` and `@Output` decorators.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Done.

Comment: what you mean by second child please share us your full code

Comment: Why you want to re render the component? Simply changing the inputs of second component won't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ChangeDetectionStaretgy.OnPush, could be usefull passing observables in your child components, and use async pipe. In this way, child components will be redrawed only on emits by observable:

First Child:

```
@Output() optionSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

selectOption() {
  this.optionSelected.emit('firstChild')
}
```

First Child html:

```
<button (click)="selectOption()">Select<button>
```

Second Child:

```
@Input() data$;
```

Second Child.html:

```
<p>{{data$ | async}}</p>
```

Parent:

```
data = new BehaviorSubject('')
setSelectedOption(val) {
  this.data.next(val)
}
```

Parent.html:

```
<first-child (optionSelected)="setSelectedOption($event)"></first-child>
<second-child [data$]=""></second-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Output` decorators is used to share data between child to parent component. `EventEmitter` is used to emit the values.

child.component.ts

```
@Output() optionSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

sendDataToChild() {
  this.optionSelected.emit('hello');
}
```

parent.component.html

In child component's selector you can listen for the event using `(optionSelected)`, when the event gets emitted `log()` method in parent components gets invoked.

```
<child-comp (optionSelected)="log($event)"></child-comp>
```

parent.component.ts

```
log(value) {
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: yeah, my question is, if value changes how i re render the second child

Comment: can you share your html files of both parent and child component, so that i can help you

Comment: I saw your question, if you share your code. its very easy for us to help you.

Comment: I used changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush and it's working. But the view update only when i hover on it

Answer (score 0):

To re-render a component dynamically you can use ComponentFactoryResolver as follows:

In your HTML template you need an 'anchor' for the new component:

```
<ng-template #child2></ng-template>
```

In your parent-component.ts you will need to reference the anchor by ViewChild and you will need to inject the ComponentFactoryResolver:

```
constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

@ViewChild('child2', { read: ViewContainerRef }) childHost: ViewContainerRef;

renderChild2(data ?: any) { // im making this optional because i dont know if you require any data to init the component
    this.childHost.clear(); // clear the current rendered component inside the anchor (if any)
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(<YOUR COMPONENT NAME>);
    const componentReference = this.childHost.createComponent(factory);
    if (data) {
        componentReference.instance.data = data; // you can access any public property/method in your component via instance
    }
}
```

All you have to do is call the renderChild2() fcn whenever you want to re-render you child2 component.